# Remove a sudden pulse on pin d3 of nodemcu when powering it up

Tags: nodemcu, relay

I am using node mcu and a 2 channel relay connected to the motor via pin d3.
When I power on the circuit, it shoots a pulse to the relay and i think it will damage the motor.
Please suggest me how to stop that pulse from turning on the motor.

Comment: Please share how you have the relay connected to your NodeMCU.  A schematic drawing would be very helpful.

Comment: Just use a different pin. Pins D1, D2, D5, D6 and D7 (GPIO's 5, 4, 14, 12, 13) are safe to use with a relay on a NodeMCU.

Answer (score 0):

D3 is GPIO0, which is used as an active low input to signal the ESP8266 bootloader to expect programming after a reset.

Use a different pin.

Comment: all esp8266 io pins are pulled up at boot

Comment: @Juraj, If that were true, and I'm not sure that it is, it's a non sequitur.  I'm curious as to why you bothered leaving this on a closed question.

Comment: pins 4+5 are the only "silent" pins on bootup